# Difference in Difference, parallel trend assumption examination

Tags: difference-in-difference

I am very new in performing the Difference in Difference analysis. Before starting the analysis, I would like to check the data if it is violated the most primary assumption 'parallel trend'. For my understanding, we should examine the trends are significantly different between case and control groups in the pre-intervention period. However, since I only have 1 study time point before the the intervention, do I still need to test the 'parallel trend'? Apparently, there is no 'trending' exists in my data since I only have 1 study timepoint. Any feedbacks appreciated.

Comment: Welcome. Can you get more data pre-intervention?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the question. We only have 1 time point data before the intervention.